# Bean validation not firing in my Spring Batch project with Spring version 4.1.7.RELEASE and Spring Batch version 3.0.4.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-batch, bean-validation

Here is my test case, it is throwing the expected org.springframework.batch.item.validator.ValidationException. The commentor below helped and so did http://springbatchbyexample.blogspot.com/2014/09/validation-input-data.html

```
     @Autowired
 MdwValidatingItemProcessor mdwValidatingItemProcessor;

 @Test(expected = ValidationException.class)
 public void notNullOnProperty(){
     MecMdw mecMdw = new MecMdw();
     //nothing set, property "lob" is null

     mdwValidatingItemProcessor.process(mecMdw);         
 }
```

I have the following domain object that is using javax.validation.constraints.NotNull:

```
 import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;


public class MecMdw {

@NotNull
private String lob;
```

The versions of Spring and Spring Batch are:

```
    <spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>      
    <spring.batch.version>3.0.4.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
```

I have the following libraries added to my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> 
       <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId> 
       <version>4.0.2.GA</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId> 
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId> 
        <version>1.5.4</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId> 
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId> 
        <version>1.5.4</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

And in my Spring Batch job XML I have wired up the validator so:

```
<bean id="mdwValidatingItemProcessor" class="com.my.itemprocessor.MdwValidatingItemProcessor">
    <property name="validator">
        <bean class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean" /> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

The MdwValidatingItemProcessor  looks as follows, again for this test case, I am able to enter into the process method, while debugging:

```
public class MdwValidatingItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<MecMdw, MecMdw> {  

private Validator validator;  

public void setValidator(Validator validator) {  
     this.validator = validator;  
}  

@Override 
public MecMdw process(MecMdw item) throws Exception {  

     BindingResult results = BindAndValidate(item);  
     if (results.hasErrors())  
          buildValidationException(results);  

     //TODO write to kickout table
     return item;  
}  

private BindingResult BindAndValidate(MecMdw item) {  
     DataBinder binder = new DataBinder(item);  
     binder.setValidator(validator);  

     binder.validate();  

     return binder.getBindingResult();  

}  

private void buildValidationException(BindingResult results) {  
     StringBuilder msg = new StringBuilder();  
     for (ObjectError error : results.getAllErrors()) {  
          msg.append("-*-*-*- \n" + error.toString() + "-*-*-*- \n");  
     }  
     throw new ValidationException(msg.toString());  
}
```

This came courtsey of http://springbatchbyexample.blogspot.com/2014/09/validation-input-data.html

Comment: Why do you have your own validator? Why not use the one provided by spring? And there is nothing going to be validated as you have override the  `process` method, so nothing is going to be validated because you broke the default behavior.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed to use org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean, and it is working. I updated my sample code in my question to reflect what worked for me.